# XML generated by XMLWriter in WCF Custom Encoder generating namespace conflict

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, xml-namespaces

I'm using a custom encoder in my WCF application to write out the SOAP message XML. When I use the default XML `textMessageEncoding` built into WCF it's fine, but when I use a custom encoder I get a problem with the namespaces - the **xmlns:a** tag below (in the  element and the  element) is defined twice for two different namespaces and this is causing problems on the service side when parsing

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action a:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" **xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"**></Action>
    <MessageID u:Id="_4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <!--Omitted-->
    </MessageID>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">
      <!--Omitted-->
    </ActivityId>
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue? I'm using the C# `XmlWriter` in the custom encoder to write the XML and that's what seems to be causing the issue.

Also, how do I get the `XmlWriter` to use a prefix for the `<Action>` tag above so that it's `<a:Action>` rather than using the xmlns for every declaration -

```
<Action a:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
```

Here's my XmlWriterSettings

```
XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
writerSettings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(factory.CharSet);
writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
writerSettings.NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by using a `XmlDictionaryWriter` instead of an `XmlWriter`. Luckily I'm using Utf-8 encoding and had the option to do this